# Memory allocation for return value of a function in a loop in C++11: how does it optimize?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, c++11

I'm in the mood for some premature optimization and was wondering the following.

If one has a for-loop, and inside that loop there is a call to a function that returns a container, say a vector, of which the value is caught as an rvalue into a variable in the loop using move semantics, for instance:

```
std::vector<any_type> function(int i)
{
  std::vector<any_type> output(3);
  output[0] = i;
  output[1] = i*2;
  output[2] = i-3;
  return(output);
}

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    // stuff
    auto value = function(i);
    // do stuff with value ...
    // ... but in such a way that it can be discarded in the next iteration
  }
}
```

How do compilers handle this memory-wise in the case that move semantics are applied (and that the function will not be inlined)? I would imagine that the most efficient thing to do is to allocate a single piece of memory for all the values, both inside the function and outside in the for-loop, that will get overwritten in each iteration.

I am mainly interested in this, because in my real-life application the vectors I'm creating are a lot larger than in the example given here. I am concerned that if I use functions like this, the allocation and destruction process will take up a lot of useless time, because I already know that I'm going to use that fixed amount of memory a lot of times. So, what I'm actually asking is whether there's some way that compilers would optimize to something of this form:

```
void function(int i, std::vector<any_type> &output)
{
  // fill output
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<any_type> dummy; // allocate memory only once
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    // stuff
    function(i, dummy);
    // do stuff with dummy
  }
}
```

In particular I'm interested in the GCC implementation, but would also like to know what, say, the Intel compiler does.

Comment: With GCC you can use the `-S` option to tell it to generate assembler code instead of an object/executable file, then check the generated assembly code to see what it does.

Comment: Hm, I have never looked at assembly code before, but I'll give it a go, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would imagine that the most efficient thing to do is to allocate a
>   single piece of memory for all the values, both inside the function
>   and outside in the for-loop, that will get overwritten in each
>   iteration.

**I don't think that any of the current compilers can do that.** (I would be stunned to see that.) If you want to get insights, watch [Chandler Carruth's talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eR34r7HOU14).

If you need this kind of optimization, you need to do it yourself: Allocate the vector outside the loop and pass it by non-const reference to `function()` as argument. Of course, don't forget to call `clear()` when you are done or call `clear()` first inside `function()`.

All this has nothing to do with move semantics, nothing has changed with C++11 in this respect.

If your loop is a busy loop, than allocating a container in each iteration can cost you a lot. It's easier to find yourself in such a situation than you would probably expect. Andrei Alexandrescu presents an example in his talk [Writing Quick Code in C++, Quickly](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Writing-Quick-Code-in-Cpp-Quickly). The surprising thing is that **doing unnecessary heap allocations in a tight loop like the one in his example can be slower than the actual file IO.** I was surprised to see that. By the way, the container was `std::string`.

Comment: I updated my question a bit just before I read your answer. Indeed, I can do it myself, as I now suggested in the second code example. If indeed that cannot be done by the compiler then that's that. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @egpbos Yeah, I am sorry, basically none of the current compilers will be that smart to do this transformation. Here at StackOverflow, we don't say thank you, we upvote and accept answers instead. ;)

Comment: I'll wait for just a little longer before accepting your answer. Maybe someone will come by to write a new compiler for me to give me what I want :P

Comment: @egpbos I can only recommend Chandler's talk that I linked in the answer. It will disillusion you about the capabilities of the current compilers. :( It's not that it is *impossible* to do it; it's just too complicated to implement it in practice. Yeah, disappointing.

Answer (score 5):

Here, the most predictable optimization is RVO. When a function return an object, if it is used to initialize a new variable, the compiler can elide additional copy and move to construct directly on the destination ( it means that a program can contains two versions of the function depending on the use case ).

Here, you will still pay for allocating and destroying a buffer inside the vector at each loo iteration. If it is unacceptable, you will have to rely on an other solution, like std::array as your function seems to use fixed size dimension or move the vector before the loop and reuse it.